# How to make copies of all the files with a certain extension, and rename the extension of the copies?

Tags: bash, command-line, copy, command

For example, I want to match all the files in the current directory with `.template`, make copies and rename it to `.fruit`.

###### Before

```
apple.template
pineapple.template
orange.template
book.ex
desk.tx
```

###### After

```
apple.template      <-- old
pineapple.template  <-- old
orange.template     <-- old
book.ex             <-- old
desk.ex             <-- old
apple.fruit         <-- new
pineapple.fruit     <-- new
orange.fruit        <-- new
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this with a simple loop:

```
for i in *.template
do 
    cp "$i" "${i%.template}.fruit"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
ls -1q *template | sed -s 's/.template$//' | xargs -I {} cp "{}.template" "{}.fruit"
```

You take all the files ending .template, get their base-name (without the extension), and copy the file to the one with the new extension.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: @Cyrus You're right :). I will make it slightly safer, obviously `find -type f -name "*.template"` is another decent option

Answer (score 0):

```
while read FILE
do
   cp "$FILE" "${FILE%.*}".fruit
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.template")
```